# How to prevent password expiration in apache Archiva

Tags: security

I  am running a standalone Archiva 2.2.0 installation. I added `security.properties` file to  `~\conf` directory. In `security.properties` I defined:

```
security.policy.password.expiration.days=999999
security.policy.password.expiration.enabled=false
```

However, Archiva keeps complaining that the admin password has expired.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me to get this to work for Archiva 2.2.0 I had to edit {archiva root}\conf\archiva.xml. There's a password section and within that is expiration where you can configure if it is enabled or not and set the number of days. Creating a security.properties did not work for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can configure via the Archiva web interface:

Section **Users Runtime Configuration** > **Properties**

At page 3, set as **false** the property **security.policy.password.expiration.enabled**

Save!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are editing the wrong file? I assume this because [in this blog post](https://bondailylog.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/apache-archiva-password-expiration-diable/) there is stated a quite different path.

The path stated in the blog post is:

```
{Archiva Server}\apps\archiva\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\maven\archiva\security.properties
```